# Scroll to an element's position within an <ol>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an OL list of items.  Within the html of those items the user can click a link and a form will slide down.  The form has a submit button on it.  I would like the OL to scroll to that button.  How can I do this?

I tried `$('#buttonId').scrollTop(xxxx)` and that didn't work.  I realized I need to scroll the OL.  `$('ol').scrollTop(xxxx)` moves the scrollbar.  How do I get the appropriate value for xxxx so the list will scroll to the desired button element?  There literally may be hundreds of items in the OL. Something tells me it must be the number of pixels between the button and the top of the OL.  If thats correct, how does one go about calculating that? Thanks so much for any tips or tricks or samples.

```
<li>
  <article  class="discussion">
   <section class="replies-container">
   <ol class="replies"></ol>
   <form>
     <fieldset class="reply">
    <textarea  placeholder="Type here to reply to this discussion." maxlength="350"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn action"/> 
         </fieldset>    
       </form>      
</section>              
</article>
 </li>
```

I want to scroll the parent OL of this html snippet to the position of submit button `$('input.btn.action')`.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$("#button").scrollTop($("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top);
```

You might also take a look at the [jQuery ScrollTo Plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/):

```
$.scrollTo("#element", 800);
```

Here are some demos:
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 1):

The [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) scrolls to an element, taking the position and everything into account: http://jsfiddle.net/U8sFx/4/.

```
$('#ol').scrollTo('li:eq(1)', 2000);
// scroll within the ol to the second li within it
// 2000 makes for a 2 second smooth animation
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins like `scrollTo` which do this easily, but I didn't need all the bloat on my website.

I used this code to achieve the effect:

```
$('a#scrollTo').click(function() {
  var top = $('element').position().left;

  $('#parent').animate({scrollTop: top + $('#parent').scrollTop()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using named anchors? If you use the name attribute of an A tag, you can get the page to jump to it when clicking a link by specifying the name after the # character in the src attribute of a second A tag.

```
<a name="scrollToHere">Destination</a>

<a href="#scrollToHere">Go to Destination</a>
```